# Python/PyCharm, new to Python package and syntax issues

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am extremely new to python and have been learning basics via DataCamp.
I downloaded Python 3 and PyCharm to use it with and all was going okay with me replicating what i was learning in DataCamp into PyCharm.

I am now trying to install packages into PyCharm and the standard way (demonstrated in Data Camp) isnt working

I have opened a new .pynfile and typed 'pip install Scrapy' but everything is underlined red (below). When i hover over the 'install' part it says that the 'Statement seems to have no effect'

[pip install Scrapy with red squiggly lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYwS.png)

Am i doing this wrong.

Secondly, I have tried to install the Scrapy package by going to settings and have faced a bunch of different errors. i finally downloaded most of what i think i needed, including the 'twisted' package (i had to download this manually). But PyCharm again isnt letting me install this package.

I read online it needed to be downloaded using this method python -m pip install C:\Users%USER%\Downloads\Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl but again this didnt work. I even opened up the Python.exe and ran this, replacing the file name with the correct path and it errored saying invalid syntax.

Please help !

Updated to add pic of cmd error

[pic of error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTYVo.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTYVo.png)

Updated to add PyCharm Error

```
command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-20efmwoj\\twisted_efc7d2a70fcd40639034d265eeb0e045\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-20efmwoj\\twisted_efc7d2a70fcd40639034d265eeb0e045\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-abp6_zhs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You're writing it in a .py file, which is a syntax error in Python

Comment: like i said i am so new to this, thanks for pointing out a blatant mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm uses his own package manager. Open File->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter and search the "+" button on the right. In the new window that just appeared, you can search and install any package you want.

Comment: Hello Thanks for replying!


When i do that it just comes out with this very long error

Answer (score 0):

PIP is Python's package installer. You can use PIP by running it from the command line (CMD, so outside of PyCharm).

**Opening the CMD:**

- Windows button + R (on windows)
- Enter `cmd` and then press enter. Now you can execute the following command:

`pip install scrapy`

which will install the `scrapy` package

Probably PyCharm can immediately use it, but restarting PyCharm performs magic!

Comment: I have tried to follow these very simple instructions and it says pip is not recognised, i will try to add the picture to the original post

Comment: @saffy you need to add Python to PATH: https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/#:~:text=How%20to%20Manually%20Add%20Python%20to%20the%20Windows,the%20PATH%20With%20the%20System%20Variables%20Option.%20

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment, you need to add python to PATH. You can do this following this tutorial: [https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/#:~:text=How%20to%20Manually%20Add%20Python%20to%20the%20Windows,the%20PATH%20With%20the%20System%20Variables%20Option.%20](https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Manually%20Add%20Python%20to%20the%20Windows,the%20PATH%20With%20the%20System%20Variables%20Option.%20). Then run `pip install scrapy` in the command prompt and that will work. Make sure you restart command prompt.